# Heritage of id in hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, inheritance

I have in BD the tables MOBILE and VESSEL. There is a relationship of heritage between them. MOBILE is the parent and VESSEL has a foreign key to have the same id.

In Java I have 2 classes:

```
@Entity
public class Mobile implements Serializable, ITechnicalBO {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Integer id;

    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name = "id")
    private Vessel vessel;

{.................}

}


@Entity
public class Vessel implements java.io.Serializable, ITechnicalBO {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Integer id;

    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name = "id")
    private Mobile mobile;

{.................}

}
```

I need to declare well the id's. I've found a lot of similar themes by internet but i'm not able to solve my problem.

How I have really to declare the id's to say to Hibernate that must generate the id of VESSEL assigning the id of MOBILE?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You said Mobile is the parent, so Vessel should extend Mobile:

```
@Entity
@PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(name = "id_vessel", referencedColumnName = "id_mobile")
public class Vessel extends Mobile implements java.io.Serializable {

    @Column(name="id_vessel", insertable =  false, updatable = false)
    private Integer id;
    // Vessel inherits all the fields from Mobile. You can add some if you want.
}

@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy=InheritanceType.JOINED)
public class Mobile implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name="id_mobile")
    private Integer id;

    // Some fields
}
```